# How to view xacro in graphiz

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use urdf_to_graphiz to quickly check your URDF's links. How do you do this directly with an Xacro file?

Currently, you have to directly convert it first, but this is a little clunky:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py -o mybot.urdf mybot.urdf.xacro
urdf_to_graphiz mybot.urdf
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209456/how-to-view-xacro-in-graphiz/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik you cannot do this 'directly'. Those tools try to kiss: `xacro.py` only coverts to urdf, `urdf_to_graphviz` takes a urdf and creates a diagram.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0